# Помогите остановить поток метода, который достает информацию о треке из online-stream (радио)

Tags: многопоточность

Кто может помочь остановить поток?

в метод: `void getTrackMetaData(String mLinkToChannel)`

передается (из `StationSwitcher`) ссылка на онлайн-стрим (радиостанция). Этот метод каждые 3 сек делает запрос и вытаскивает из  потока данные о песне которая играет. Более того, сразу в этом же методе обновляется и `TextView` с информацией о треке:   `titleTextView.post(...)`

Соответственно, если включить одну станцию и не переключать, то все работает хорошо). В `TextView` выводится, и если меняется трек - обновляется информация о треке. Однако, если переключить станцию, т.е. запустить метод опять(из `StationSwitcher`) с новой ссылкой, то работает и старый поток (со старой ссылкой), и создается новый.

Вопрос в том, как остановить старый поток?

```
private void getTrackMetaData(String mLinkToChannel) {
  final Utils.TrackData[] trackData = new Utils.TrackData[1];
  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
              try {
                  Thread.sleep(3000);
                  try {
                      URL url = new URL(mLinkToChannel) 
                      ParsingHeaderData streaming = new ParsingHeaderData();
                      trackData[0] = streaming.getTrackDetails(url);
                      artistTextView.post(new Runnable() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void run() {
                                          artistTextView.setText(                                                      
                                        ((trackData[0].artist).equals("")) ? 
                                           mTitleGag : trackData[0].artist);
                                      }
                      });
                      titleTextView.post(new Runnable() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void run() {
                                         titleTextView.setText(   
                                         ((trackData[0].title).equals("")) ?
                                             " " : trackData[0].title);
                                     }
                      });
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                } catch (InterruptedException x) {e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

p/s

**Utils.TrackData** - класс в котором два поля String: `artist` и `title`.

**ParsingHeaderData** - класс, который лезет в поток и достает объект типа `Utils.TrackData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код с решением проблемы находится тут
http://pastebin.com/AmteatPr

```
public class TrackInfoUpdator {

    private static final String DEFAULT_TILE = "default_title";
    private static final String DEFAULT_ARTIST = "default_artist";

    public static void demo() {
        Callback callback = (title, artist) -> {
            titleTextView.setText(title);
            artistTextView.setText(artist);
        };

        // this is field of your activity/fragment
        TrackInfoUpdator updator = new TrackInfoUpdator(callback);

        // somewhere in onResume()
        updator.startTracking("anyLink here");

        // somewhere in onPause()
        updator.stopTracking();
    }


    private final Handler uiHandler;
    private final Callback callback;

    // not marked as volatile, used only from UI thread
    private UpdatorThread backgroundThread;

    public TrackInfoUpdator(Callback callback) {
        this.uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @UiThread
    public void startTracking(String link) {
        stopTracking();
        backgroundThread = new UpdatorThread(uiHandler, callback, link);
        backgroundThread.start();
    }

    @UiThread
    public void stopTracking() {
        if (backgroundThread != null) {
            backgroundThread.disable();
            backgroundThread = null;
        }
    }

    private static class UpdatorThread extends Thread {

        private static final int MSECS_REPEAT = 3000;

        private final Handler callbackThread;
        private final Callback callback;
        private final String link;
        private volatile boolean isDisabled = false;

        public UpdatorThread(Handler callbackThread, Callback callback, String link) {
            this.callbackThread = callbackThread;
            this.callback = callback;
            this.link = link;
        }

        public void disable() {
            isDisabled = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!isDisabled) {
                try {
                    waitForRepeat();
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
                try {
                    fetchData();
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }
        }

        private void waitForRepeat() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(MSECS_REPEAT);
        }

        private void fetchData() throws Exception {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            ParsingHeaderData streaming = new ParsingHeaderData();
            Utils.TrackData trackData = streaming.getTrackDetails(url);

            String title = TextUtils.isEmpty(trackData.title) ? DEFAULT_TITLE : trackData.title;
            String artist = TextUtils.isEmpty(trackData.artist) ? DEFAULT_ARTIST : trackData.artist;

            callbackThread.post(() -> {
                if (!isDisabled) {
                    callback.onTrackInfoUpdated(title, artist);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void onTrackInfoUpdated(String title, String artist);
    }

}
```